# Properties with the same name in base and derived DataContracts, cause error in auto-generated service reference

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, serialization, service

Alright, here's the situation:

DataContract FileRouterConfig is derived from RouterConfig (also a DataContract).

Both have a property SendType.
In RouterConfig (base):

```
public string SendType
{
    get { return sendType; }
    set { sendType = value; }
}
```

In FileRouterConfig (derived):

```
    [DataMember(Name = "SendType")]
    public new string SendType
    {
        get { return base.SendType; }
        set { base.SendType = value; }
    }
```

Now another project which uses automatically generated service reference (which involves FileRouterConfig above), fails to build with this error in auto generated reference.cs:

> Warning as Error: 'FileRouterConfig.SendType' hides
>   inherited member
>   'RouterConfig.SendType'. Use the new
>   keyword if hiding was intended.

How can I avoid this, without changing the DataMember name attribute which would violate existing data contract??
Notice that I've already used new keyword in the FileRouterConfig class.

Comment: Why are you doing this? The derived property is precisely the same as the base property.

Comment: Actually, some other classes derived from RouterConfig use the SendType property. So can't remove it from there. I just wanted to remove the DataMember attribute of SendType from RouterConfig and move it to only the classes that need it.

Comment: But why do you want to remove `[DataMember]`?

Comment: So that SendType doesn't appear in all of the DataContracts derived from RouterConfig, just in the ones that need it.

Comment: So, in that case, you don't have a true inheritance hierarchy. Seriously, just live with the extra member.